# How to calculate hours to minutes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing some problems where I want the time remaining to be shown as hours and minutes.

The issue now is that when calculating the time, it shows for example `1.97` hours. I want the time to be like `1.30` (1h30min).

I am also facing a problem where the time is reached, I want the remaining time to be calculated to the next `open`.

Below is the code I have done so far:

```js
var openTime = [{
    open: -1,
    close: -1
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 17
}]

var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var nextday = current.getDay()+1;
var currentTime = current.getHours() + (current.getMinutes() / 60);
var remainTime = 0;
if (openTime[day].close - (currentTime).toFixed(2) >= 0) {
    remainTime = (openTime[day].close - currentTime).toFixed(2)
console.log("close in %s hours", remainTime);
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "close in " + remainTime+ " hours"
}
else if (openTime[day].close - (currentTime).toFixed(2) <= 0) {
     remainTime = (currentTime).toFixed(2) + (openTime[nextday].open)
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "open in " + remainTime+ " hours"
}
```

```html
<div id="hours"></div>
```

Comment: What is `1.97` supposed to be in your notation? `2h37m` or `1h58m`?

Comment: What will make this easier is to represent the time in minutes instead of hour fractions. For example: `currentTime = (current.getHours() * 60) + current.getMinutes()` and convert the time in hours and minutes after the checks and calculations are done.

Comment: Working with time is complicated, because not every day has 24 hours, and not every month has only 30 or 31 days, etc. I would recommend to consider using a library like `moment.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this. converted your open and close time to minutes and current time also to minutes and calculated the remaining time

```js
var openTime = [{
    open: -1,
    close: -1
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 10
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 21
}, {
    open: 8,
    close: 17
}]

var current = new Date();
var day = current.getDay();
var nextday = current.getDay()+1;
var currentTime = currentTime = (current.getHours() * 60) + current.getMinutes();
var remainTime = 0;
var closeTime = (openTime[day].close *60);
var openTime = (openTime[day].open *60);
if (closeTime - currentTime >= 0) {
    remainTime = closeTime - currentTime;
    
console.log("close in %s minutes", remainTime);
var hours = Math.floor(remainTime/60);
  if(hours == 0){
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "close in " + Math.floor(remainTime%60) + " Mins";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "close in " + hours+ " hours " + Math.floor(remainTime%60) + " Mins";
  }
}
else if (closeTime - currentTime <= 0) {
     remainTime = currentTime + openTime;
document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "open in " + Math.floor(remainTime/60)+ " hours" + Math.floor(remainTime%60) + " Mins";
}
```

```html
<div id="hours"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to hide `"hours"` when the time remaining is below 1h. I am not sure how that code should look like and where to put it in the `if-statement`, could you help out? @syed

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have run in to some issues when lookinng at the code. I am trying to have the code `else if (closeTime - currentTime <= 0) {
     remainTime = currentTime + openTime;` to calculate to the `openTime` the day after. Right now it is calculating the `openTime` that is on the same day. I have tried with `nextday` but can't get it to work. @syed

Comment: Any news? @syed

Answer (score 3):

```js
function timeConvert(n) {
    var num = n;
    var hours = (num / 60);
    var rhours = Math.floor(hours);
    var minutes = (hours - rhours) * 60;
    var rminutes = Math.round(minutes);
    return num + " minutes = " + rhours + " hour(s) and " + rminutes + " minute(s).";
    }
    console.log(timeConvert(200));
```

I think you can go with this.

Answer (score 0):

please adjust closing time in closing function parameter to test. Hope it helps.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a8v3dtfb/1/)

```js
function closing(closing_time) {
let current_datetime = new Date();
let formatted_date = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate()

var closing = new Date(formatted_date + " "+closing_time);

// get total seconds between the times
var delta = Math.abs(current_datetime - closing) / 1000;

// calculate (and subtract) whole hours
var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
delta -= hours * 3600;


// calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
delta -= minutes * 60;

//alert(minutes);

alert("Remaining time to go home : " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "minutes");
}

closing("06:30 PM");
```